# Close a file which is in use from a PictureBox

Tags: c#

I'm using this code for converting Excel to image and preview it in a picturebox.
The code is working for first time. But when i'm trying to upload second time i get an error that says that the image file is in use.specically in save point.

```
  OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "bak files (*.xls)|*.xls|All files (*.*)|*.*";
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            Img1 = openFileDialog1.FileName;


            //Create a new Workbook object and
            //Open a template Excel file.
            Workbook book = new Workbook(Img1);
            //Get the first worksheet.
            Worksheet sheet = book.Worksheets[0];

            //Define ImageOrPrintOptions
            ImageOrPrintOptions imgOptions = new ImageOrPrintOptions();
            //Specify the image format
            imgOptions.ImageFormat = System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg;
            //Only one page for the whole sheet would be rendered
            imgOptions.OnePagePerSheet = true;

            //Render the sheet with respect to specified image/print options
            SheetRender sr = new SheetRender(sheet, imgOptions);
            //Render the image for the sheet
            Bitmap bitmap = sr.ToImage(0);

            //Save the image file specifying its image format.
            bitmap.Save("C:\\1.jpg");\\in this point i get my error that it says general error  GDI+.

            pictureBox2.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\\1.jpg");
            pictureBox2.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;

        }
        else
        {
            this.DialogResult = DialogResult.None;

        }
    }
```

I thing i must stop first use from my picturebox preview and then to upload again. But how will i do that? I tried

```
 pictureBox1.Image=null
```

,but it didnt worked.

Comment: You need to check if the 1.jpg exists if so delete it then save it.

Comment: If i will try to delete it it says that the file is been used from another process. It works only if i will re-run my project.I think that the problem is here pictureBox2.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\\1.jpg");
            pictureBox2.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;

Comment: You need to dispose of the picturebox image as Johan suggested: if (pictureBox2.Image != null) pictureBox2.Image.Dispose();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use

```
pictureBox2.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\\1.jpg");
```

The static call keeps the file open (and locked). So you can't overwrite the file.

Solution:

```
if (pictureBox2.Image != null) pictureBox2.Image.Dispose();
bitmap.Save("C:\\1.jpg");
bitmap.Dispose();
pictureBox2.Image = new Bitmap(Image.FromFile("C:\\1.jpg"));
```

This way the file is released and can later be overwritten.

An alternative:

```
if (pictureBox2.Image != null) pictureBox2.Image.Dispose();
bitmap.Save("C:\\1.jpg");
bitmap.Dispose();
using (Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(C:\\1.jpg"))
{
   pictureBox2.Image = new Bitmap(bm);
};
```

Comment: Same error generela information error GDI+.Should i try dispose bitmap?

Comment: My bad: the bitmap.Save(..) call also locks the file until the bitmap is disposed.  Edited the solution above...

Note: the file the bitmap is saved to is an unmanaged resource, so even when you assign a new image to bitmap (from sr) and there is no longer a reference to the old bitmap instance, the associated file is still kept open. A dispose of the bitmap object will release the unmanaged resource (the file).

Comment: Same error again.The problem is in this line pictureBox2.Image = new Bitmap(Image.FromFile("C:\\1.jpg"));. If i will remove this line it saves without any problem

Comment: Try disposing the picturebox image as well before saving the new version (see code above)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using FileStream.

```
  Dim fs1 As System.IO.FileStream
            fs1 = New System.IO.FileStream(Bitmap, IO.FileMode.Open, IO.FileAccess.Read)
            PictureBox1.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(fs1)
            fs1.Close()
```

Look that you should `fs1.close()` to finish the stream.

The FileStream Class represents a File in the machine. FileStream allows to move data to and from the stream as arrays of bytes. It means, it does'nt works directly in the file, just as a Stream that you can manipulate.

The code is in vb.net (because it works for me). 
So there will be no problem translating it to C #

Answer (score 0):

Here VB.NET Example for opening Image in picture box without keeping file locked for other operation.
**VB.NET Code.**

```
Dim fs As System.IO.FileStream
' Specify a valid picture file path on your computer.
fs = New System.IO.FileStream("C:\WINNT\Web\Wallpaper\Fly Away.jpg",
     IO.FileMode.Open, IO.FileAccess.Read)
PictureBox1.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(fs)
fs.Close()
```

**C# Code.**

```
System.IO.FileStream fs;
// Specify a valid picture file path on your computer.
fs = new System.IO.FileStream(@"C:\WINNT\Web\Wallpaper\Fly Away.jpg", System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read);
PictureBox1.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(fs);
fs.Close();
```

**Reference -** 
https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/492654/5bc-23-5dplusdeleteplusimagepluswhichplusisplusope